# It's slower to calculate integral image using CUDA than CPU code

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, cuda, textures

I am implementing the integral image calculation module using CUDA to improve performance.
But its speed slower than the CPU module.
Please let me know what i did wrong.
cuda kernels and host code follow.
And also, another problem is...
In the kernel SumH, using texture memory is slower than global one, imageTexture was defined as below.

```
texture<unsigned char, 1> imageTexture;
cudaBindTexture(0, imageTexture, pbImage);
```

// kernels to scan the image horizontally and vertically.

```
__global__ void SumH(unsigned char* pbImage, int* pnIntImage, __int64* pn64SqrIntImage, float rVSpan, int nWidth)
{
    int nStartY, nEndY, nIdx;
    if (!threadIdx.x)
    {
        nStartY = 1;
    }
    else
        nStartY = (int)(threadIdx.x * rVSpan);
    nEndY = (int)((threadIdx.x + 1) * rVSpan);

    for (int i = nStartY; i < nEndY; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < nWidth; j ++)
        {
            nIdx = i * nWidth + j;
            pnIntImage[nIdx] = pnIntImage[nIdx - 1] + pbImage[nIdx - nWidth - i];
            pn64SqrIntImage[nIdx] = pn64SqrIntImage[nIdx - 1] + pbImage[nIdx - nWidth - i] * pbImage[nIdx - nWidth - i];
            //pnIntImage[nIdx] = pnIntImage[nIdx - 1] + tex1Dfetch(imageTexture, nIdx - nWidth - i);
            //pn64SqrIntImage[nIdx] = pn64SqrIntImage[nIdx - 1] + tex1Dfetch(imageTexture, nIdx - nWidth - i) * tex1Dfetch(imageTexture, nIdx - nWidth - i);
        }
    }
}
__global__ void SumV(unsigned char* pbImage, int* pnIntImage, __int64* pn64SqrIntImage, float rHSpan, int nHeight, int nWidth)
{
    int nStartX, nEndX, nIdx;
    if (!threadIdx.x)
    {
        nStartX = 1;
    }
    else
        nStartX = (int)(threadIdx.x * rHSpan);
    nEndX = (int)((threadIdx.x + 1) * rHSpan);

    for (int i = 1; i < nHeight; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = nStartX; j < nEndX; j ++)
        {
            nIdx = i * nWidth + j;
            pnIntImage[nIdx] = pnIntImage[nIdx - nWidth] + pnIntImage[nIdx];
            pn64SqrIntImage[nIdx] = pn64SqrIntImage[nIdx - nWidth] + pn64SqrIntImage[nIdx];
        }
    }
}
```

// host code

```
    int nW = image_width;
    int nH = image_height;
    unsigned char* pbImage;
    int* pnIntImage;
    __int64* pn64SqrIntImage;
    cudaMallocManaged(&pbImage, nH * nW);
    // assign image gray values to pbimage
    cudaMallocManaged(&pnIntImage, sizeof(int) * (nH + 1) * (nW + 1));
    cudaMallocManaged(&pn64SqrIntImage, sizeof(__int64) * (nH + 1) * (nW + 1));
    float rHSpan, rVSpan;
        int nHThreadNum, nVThreadNum;
        if (nW + 1 <= 1024)
        {
            rHSpan = 1;
            nVThreadNum = nW + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            rHSpan = (float)(nW + 1) / 1024;
            nVThreadNum = 1024;
        }
        if (nH + 1 <= 1024)
        {
            rVSpan = 1;
            nHThreadNum = nH + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            rVSpan = (float)(nH + 1) / 1024;
            nHThreadNum = 1024;
        }

        SumH<<<1, nHThreadNum>>>(pbImage, pnIntImage, pn64SqrIntImage, rVSpan, nW + 1);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        SumV<<<1, nVThreadNum>>>(pbImage, pnIntImage, pn64SqrIntImage, rHSpan, nH + 1, nW + 1);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

Comment: `SumH<<<1, nHThreadNum>>>` - this is telling the GPU you want 1 block, nHThreadNum threads. This is extremely inefficient as it will only run on one of the GPUs streaming multiprocessors, of which there may be up to 15. Splitting your work into multiple blocks would be a good start.

Comment: @Jez if you want to provide an answer along those lines, I would upvote.  It's a significant deficiency in the OP's code and is probably the best starting point for improvement.

Comment: Jez, I can't understand clearly, i launched the 1024 threads which is maximum. they don't run parallel? even though, in case using block, the maximum number of usable threads is 1024, since i thought, the performance is regard to the number of threads. they are the same, ain't i right?

Comment: i changed the code using blocks like this nBlockNum = 32, nHThreadNum = 32, SumH<<<nBlockNum, nHThreadNum>>>(...), but its speed dont improved much, i think there is another not proper part.

Comment: You might want to try using one of the `nppiSqrIntegral` functions from the [CUDA NPP library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html#axzz3ANAyKNBI).  Although they don't cover the integral function, there are [npp sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cudalibraries) that may help you get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the code that is currently in the question. There are two things I'd like to mention: launch parameters and timing methodology.

### 1) Launch parameters

When you launch a kernel there are two main arguments that specify the amount of threads you are launching. These are between the `<<<` and `>>>` sections, and are the number of blocks in the grid, and the number of threads per block as follows:

```
foo <<< numBlocks, numThreadsPerBlock >>> (args);
```

For a single kernel to be efficient on a current GPU you can use the rule of thumb that numBlocks * numThreadsPerBlock should be at least 10,000. Ie. 10,000 pieces of work. This is a rule of thumb, so you may get good results with only 5,000 threads (it varies with GPU: cheaper GPUs can get away with fewer threads), but this is the order of magnitude you need to be looking at as a minimum. **You are running 1024 threads.** This is almost certainly not enough (Hint: the loops inside your kernel look like scan primatives, these can be done in parallel).

Further to this there are a few other things to consider.

- The number of blocks should be large in comparison to the number of SMs on your GPU. A Kepler K40 has 15 SMs, and to avoid a signficant [tail effect](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-minimize-the-tail-effect/) you'd probably want at least ~100 blocks on this GPU. Other GPUs have fewer SMs, but you haven't specified which you have, so I can't be more specific.
- The number of threads per block should not be too small. You can only have so many blocks on each SM, so if your blocks are too small you will use the GPU suboptimally. Furthermore, on newer GPUs [up to four warps can receive instructions on a SM simultaneously](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#multiprocessor-level), and as such is it often a good idea to have block sizes as multiples of 128.

### 2) Timing

I'm not going to go into so much depth here, but make sure your timing is sane. GPU code tends to have a one-time initialisation delay. If this is within your timing, you will see erroneously large runtimes for codes designed to represent a much larger code. Similarly, data transfer between the CPU and GPU takes time. In a real application you may only do this once for thousands of kernel calls, but in a test application you may do it once per kernel launch.

If you want to get accurate timings you must make your example more representitive of the final code, or you must be sure that you are only timing the regions that will be repeated.

Comment: I have three questions. please guide me.
1. my gpu is Geforce gtx750, but i can't find how many SMs it have from datasheet, and also, don't know how to design the number of blocks per grid and threads per block, effectively.
2. secondly, cuda kernel function is not optimized by nvcc compiler in release mode?so the performance is equal in debug and release build mode?
3. thirdly, i am not clear at your Timing explanation(2)), what is one-time initialization delay? those are unified memory i used in my code. their transfer is also considered as the transfer between CPU and GPU?

Comment: 1) There is a tool in the SDK to determine this called deviceQuery. You can either run this, or get the value yourself from the cudaGetDeviceProporties function. 2) I cannot answer as I don't know which flags you use in each mode. 3) I suggest you experiment a bit based on my answer and if you don't understand something, post a new question with a complete code demonstrating what you've tried and what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is to profile the code, but in this case we can probably make a reasonable guess.

You're basically just doing a single scan through some data, and doing extremely minimal processing on each item.

Given how little processing you're doing on each item, the bottleneck when you process the data with the CPU is probably just reading the data from memory.

When you do the processing on the GPU, the data still needs to be read from memory and copied into the GPU's memory. That means we still have to read all the data from main memory, just like if the CPU did the processing. Worse, it all has to be written to the GPU's memory, causing a further slowdown. By the time the GPU even gets to start doing real processing, you've already used up more time than it would have taken the CPU to finish the job.

For Cuda to make sense, you generally need to be doing a lot more processing on each individual data item. In this case, the CPU is probably already nearly idle most of the time, waiting for data from memory. In such a case, the GPU is unlikely to be of much help *unless* the input data was already in the GPU's memory so the GPU could do the processing without any extra copying.

Answer (score 0):

When working with CUDA there are a few things you should keep in mind.

1. Copying from host memory to device memory is 'slow' - when you copy some data from the host to the device you should do as much calculations as possible (do all the work) before you copy it back to the host.
2. On the device there are 3 types of memory - global, shared, local. You can rank them in speed like global < shared < local (local =  fastest).
3. Reading from consecutive memory blocks is faster than random access. When working with array of structures you would like to transpose it to a structure of arrays.
4. You can always consult the [CUDA Visual Profiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw1HL6dSR1o) to show you the bottleneck of your program.

Answer (score 0):

the above mentioned GTX750 has 512 CUDA cores (these are the same as the shader units, just driven in a /different/ mode).
http://www.nvidia.de/object/geforce-gtx-750-de.html#pdpContent=2

the duty of creating integral images is only partially able to be parallel'ized as any result value in the results array depends on a bigger bunch of it's predecessors. further it is only a tiny math portion per memory transfer so the ALU powers and thus the unavoidable memory transfers might be the bottle neck. such an accelerator might provide some speed up, but not a thrilling speed up because of the duty itself does not allow it.

if you would compute multiple variations of integral images on the same input data you would be able to see the "thrill" much more likely due to much higher parallelism options and a higher amount of math ops. but that would be a different duty then.

as a wild guess from google search - others have already fiddled with those item: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD8QFjAKahUKEwjjnoabw8bIAhXFvhQKHbUpA1Y&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdspace.mit.edu%2Fopenaccess-disseminate%2F1721.1%2F71883&usg=AFQjCNHBbOEB_OHAzLZI9__lXO_7FPqdqA